# failed to get facebook access_token

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-oauth

This is a part of getting access_token taken from facebook-sdk example.
After I get the `code`, I do exactly following the example as below

```
 if self.request.get("code"):
            args["client_secret"] = FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET
            args["code"] = self.request.get("code")
            response = cgi.parse_qs(urllib.urlopen(
                "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" +
                urllib.urlencode(args)).read())
            access_token = response["access_token"][-1]
```

The error I get from `response` is

```
'{"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

This is the link I get in order to get access_token

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?code=AQD3K0Qc-9mJ1pUIWovhbO549GIk-X_y2v6VRbjFB_WtHMtINtU6GTZ4T2rBbjUr9teiGbhxsBm23xjRXhX4CfWdMXgsNXjgTOUeG9Nz6oNmgluvZwv3oQQ42w8vBTowlDGOdKvmW065WrQTLW3e8oZJ7C_XNwUl5bYDD5JF_JLD9O4BBfAGbfRHWHAf6Yy0ewaJr8MmtU-qhemYe8mQ2hrM&client_secret=xxxxx&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8088&client_id=xxxx
```

It has `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?`
`code`, `client_secret`,`redirect_uri`,`client_id`

Do I miss any parameters to get access_token?

Comment: I have had the same problem yesterday using the socialauth 3.0 library for Java. It might be a problem with the Facebook API but I have had no time to look into it yet.

Comment: Is this is related? https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/207955409343730

Comment: @ShayErlichmen : No, it does not related to that bug

Answer (score 1):

I got it. My `redirect_uri` need a dash "/" at the end of the url.

It should be "http://abc.com**/**"

Too much painful to find the mistake